# DirectoryEntries.Find: "An invalid dn syntax has been specified"

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to find a user in the current domain. The code is this:

```
DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN-Users, DC=" + Environment.UserDomainName);
            DirectoryEntries entries = domain.Children;
            try
            {
                // The following line causes the exception
                DirectoryEntry user = entries.Find("(&(objectCategory=user)(cn=" + userName + "))", ActiveDirectoryEntryType.User.TypeName);
                user.DeleteTree();
                user.CommitChanges();
            }
            catch
            {}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
An invalid dn syntax has been specified.
```

I also tried the following code and got the same error:

```
DirectoryEntry user = entries.Find(userName, ActiveDirectoryEntryType.User.TypeName);
```

I could not find information about the proper syntax in the help files. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: Hello, what the username value you are looking for on LDAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in this statemet:

```
DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN-Users, DC=" + Environment.UserDomainName);
```

I almost sure that it should be: `LDAP://CN=Users,` instaed of `LDAP://CN-Users,`

Second thing is `DC=" + Environment.UserDomainName` which maybe wrong, because ususally it is something like this: `LDAP://OU=Finance,dc=fabrikam,dc=com` (there is more than one DC)

You can find all DC using powershell. Run following command:

```
New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
```

Comment: OK, now I'm embarrassed... you're right, the CN- is the error. 
Regarding the domain - yes, I know that, I am about to change that code but it is sufficient in the meantime, since out domain name is only one word.
Thank you!