# An invalid DN syntax has been specified - Visual Studio error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, active-directory

I'm trying to make a Visual Studio program that lets you add users to an Active Directory. Whenever I add the user, I get the error "An invalid DN syntax has been specified". I don't know what this error means exactly, and Googling learned me that it could be a whole number of things. Here is the relevant code:

```
            string UserName = txt_UserName.Text;
            string Department = ddl_Department.SelectedItem.ToString(); //The chosen OU
            string LDAPstring = "LDAP://OU=" + Department + ",DC=group0, DC=han";
            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPstring);

            //Make a USER Object
            DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add(UserName, "user");
            newUser.CommitChanges(); //User is made
            newUser.Properties["userprincipalname"].Add(txt_UserName.Text + "@group0.han");
            newUser.Properties["samaccountname"].Value = txt_UserName.Text;
            newUser.CommitChanges(); //User is given properties
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168267/directoryentries-find-an-invalid-dn-syntax-has-been-specified ?

Comment: No, seems like I got another problem

Comment: what is the value of `Department`?  Better yet, what is the entire value of `LDAPstring`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be good if you change this line:

`DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add(UserName, "user");`

to this:

`DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + UserName, "user");`

Also, `userPrincipalName` isn't multivalued. Just set the value on it like you're setting the `sAMAccountName` value.